# offset().top con valor en negativo

Tags: javascript

tengo este fragmento de javascript el cual necesito añadirle un valor en negativo pero no logro que lo acepte.

```
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 10
    }, 800, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

Donde el valor se refleja en +10 deberia de poderse meten un -10, pero me da error. Muchas gracias

Comment: La posición de la barra de scroll (`scrollTop`) no debería tener valores negativos, si el cálculo de restar 10 da como resultado un valor negativo podría provocar un error (PD: acabo de probar a hacer [`scrollTop(-10)`](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/#scrollTop-value) y simplemente se queda en 0). ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Quizá puedas hacerlo de otra forma o limitar a un mínimo de 0 el resultado de la resta.

Comment: Si, recibo el mismo fallo, el problema es que cuando le scroll llega a la posicion deseada pasa que me corta el titulo, por eso pensaba en que tuviera un negativo para que quedara por encima.

Comment: He redactado una respuesta con una alternativa a tu implementación para salvar el problema del destino del scroll. Tal y como comprobé anteriormente, si el destino es negativo el scroll de pantalla se quedará en `0` (el final de la animación se detendrá bruscamente al llegar a `0`).

Answer (score 1):

He reproducido tu código con este pequeño ejemplo (pulsa para mostrar):

```css
div {
  min-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="arriba">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#uno">Uno</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dos">Dos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tres">Tres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cuatro">Cuatro</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="uno">Uno <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<div id="dos">Dos <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<div id="tres">Tres <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<div id="cuatro">Cuatro <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<script>
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 30
    }, 1800, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
</script>
```

En él no se produce ningún error como tal, aunque falla su funcionamiento porque tras terminar la animación "salta" a la posición final que tendría si no se hubiera animado de manera brusca.

El código que que coloca siempre el scroll justo a ras del destino, animes al destino `scrollTop` que sea, es el siguiente:

```
window.location.hash = target;
```

Provocará que, tras finalizar la animación, haya un salto inmediato desde donde estaba el scroll posicionado hasta el que te llevaría al hacer el clic, ignorando completamente el destino que programaras en `scrollTop`.

Para solucionarlo es mejor hacer uso del evento [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate):

> A `popstate` event is dispatched to the window each time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document.

En castellano:

> Un evento `popstate` es enviado a la ventana cada vez que la entrada el historial cambia entre dos entradas para un mismo documento.

Significa que siempre que pulses en un enlace interno (`href="#id"`) se provocará ese evento que es el encargado, entre otras cosas, de posicionar el scroll del navegador en el destino.

A continuación muestro un ejemplo de uso:

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="arriba">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#uno">Uno</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dos">Dos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tres">Tres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cuatro">Cuatro</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="uno">Uno <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<div id="dos">Dos <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<div id="tres">Tres <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<div id="cuatro">Cuatro <a href="#arriba">volver</a></div>
<script>
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    /* Evitamos que haga el "salto" indeseado */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Ahora los destinos debemos obtenerlos de hash que ya está en location */
    var target = location.hash;
    var $target = $(location.hash);
    /* Hacemos la animación y fíjate que ya te llevará a 30 pixeles por encima */
    $('html,body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': Math.max($target.offset().top - 30, 0),
    }, 1800, 'swing');
});
</script>
```

Además, como mejor que en principio no es imprescindible, he agregado un cálculo del valor máximo con [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max) entre el calculado y `0`, por lo que siempre que sea un valor negativo se configurará un `0` en su lugar.